# How to ignore ' in output by knitr

Tags: r, knitr

Is it possible to use a knitr hook or something similar to make knitr ignore a ' symbol in the output. The problem is that knitr highlights the text after the ' as a string.

Example:

[image]

In this example, I don't want the colour to change to green!

I'm using the `knitr` option `comment=NA` in R markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your error with the following setup:

```
<some latex packages>
\begin{document}
<<h,echo=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
y <- c( 2.6,  3.1,  2.5,  5.0,  3.6,  4.0,  5.2,  2.8,  3.8)
cor.test(x,y,method="pearson")
@ 
\end{document}
```

here is my pdf output

```
library(knitr)
x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
y <- c( 2.6, 3.1, 2.5, 5.0, 3.6, 4.0, 5.2, 2.8, 3.8)
cor.test(x,y,method="pearson")

## 
## Pearson’s product-moment correlation
##
## data: x and y
## t = 1.841, df = 7, p-value = 0.1082
## alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
## 95 percent confidence interval:
## -0.1497 0.8956
## sample estimates:
## cor
## 0.5712
```

Comment: you need to add `comment=NA` to the knitr statement

Comment: Perhaps using `knitr` hooks in post-processing to remove the ##?

Comment: I really didn't add any options in the above chunk beyond <<h,echo=TRUE>>=. I've just knit and compiled the tex file.